# Error when using function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, floating

I'm using a function in MATLAB for the first time. The function body is working properly., but when it is called from a program it giving an error.

The function is:

```
function f = adjust(value)
if value < 0
  s = -1;
  value = -value;
else
  s = 1;
end

b = floor(value);
value = value-b;
value = s*value;

f = sprintf('%.14f', value);
```

Main program is

```
x(1) = 0.3;
y(1) = -0.4;
a = 36;
for n = 2:16 
   temp = a*(y(n-1)-x(n-1));
   x(n) = adjust(temp);
end
```

I want to generate a number of values with precision `1e-14.`
When I run the program, I get the error

```
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
I must be the same.

Error in ==> one at 6
    x(n) = adjust(temp);"
```

I don't know what to do with this. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Do you happen to have a variable in your main program called `adjust`? You can check this with the `whos `command.

Comment: inside the loop, display the values of `n`, `temp`, `y(n-1)`, `x(n-1)`, `a`, and `adjust(temp)` *before* the line `x(n) = ...`. I think this will show where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is returning f as the output of sprintf, which is a char array.  You can't put this into x, because x has already been defined as containing doubles with `x(1)=0.3;`

You may want to use sprintf to print the value to screen so you can check it, but your function should be returning a number, `value`.

ETA: As Rody explained in the comments, `format` can be used to change how Matlab displays numbers, but the precision does not change. Similarly, `sprintf` can control the format but it doesn't change the value itself.  Try these lines at the command line:

```
format short
value = 3.000000000012
format long
value
```

Comment: thats the exact problem.but how to solve this by keeping the precision 10^-14..any ideas???

Comment: @user2689061: MATLAB's precision is always the best possible (~`1e-16` determined by IEEE754 `double`). So just returning `value` will already meet your `1e-14` demand. Now, how MATLAB *displays* values depends on your setting of `format`.